# Overridding IDs With Hibernate InheritanceType.JOINED

Tags: hibernate

Given the following situation:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@Table(name="TOP_TABLE")
public class BaseClass implements Serializable {

    private Long id;

    @Id
    public Long getId() {

    }
}

// PrimaryKeyJoinColumns
@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_A")
public class ClassA extends BaseClass {

    @Id
    public Long getId() {

    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="TABLE_B")
// Primary Key Join Columns
public class ClassB extends BaseClass {

    @Id
    public Long getId() {

    }

}
```

I have two questions:

- In InheritanceType.JOINED, can a subclass override the id of the parent? This is because:
- If the Ids are generated via sequence, can the id for each subclass have separate sequence generators?

Thanks for any help.

Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass cannot override id, because id can be defined only once in hierarchy. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told as follows:

> The primary key must be defined on the entity class that is the root
>   of the entity hierarchy or on a mapped superclass that is a (direct or
>   indirect) superclass of all entity classes in the entity hierarchy.
>   The primary key must be defined exactly once in an entity hierarchy.

Also there is no Hibernate specific support for this. Only thing, what it comes to @Id that can be done differently in leaf of inheritance hierarchy is defining different name for id column via [PrimaryKeyJoinColumn](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PrimaryKeyJoinColumn.html).